# Multiple value-formats in a formatted string

Tags: python-3.x, format

Is it possible to combine more than one colon-format-string?
Example:

```
val = 2.123
print(f'This is a float-value with one digit: {val:.1f} and balanced to right with {val:>10}')
```

so, something like {val:.1f:>10}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Format Specification Mini Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) . You were just off with the order, `f'{val:>10.1f}'` works for this specific example.

`>` is align, `10` is width, `.1` is precision and `f` is type.

Comment: In fact I stepped over the doc but obviously did not understand it... Thanks a lot.